# Найти повторяющиеся значения списка

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Задание следующее:

> Напишите программу, которая принимает на вход список чисел в одной
> строке и выводит на экран в одну строку значения, которые встречаются
> в нём более одного раза.
>
> Для решения задачи может пригодиться метод *sort* списка.
>
> Выводимые числа не должны повторяться, порядок их вывода может быть
> произвольным.

Вот мое решение:

```
s = [int(i) for i in input().split()]
s.sort()
cnt = 1
l = len(s)

for i in range(l-2):
    if s[i] == s[i + 1] and s[i + 1] != s[i + 2]:
        cnt += 1
        if cnt > 1:
            print(s[i], end=" ")
            cnt = 1
```

Программа работает на примере `"4 8 0 3 4 2 0 3"`, выводит `"0 3 4"`. Если ввести одно число, то тоже работает (то есть ничего не выводит, так и должно быть).

Но если ввести `"1 1 2 2 3 3"`, то выводит `"1 2"`, хотя должно быть "1 2 3". Или если ввести `"1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2"`, то выводит `"1"`, хотя должно быть `"1 2"`.

Объясните, пожалуйста, что не так?

PS `set` и `count` желательно не использовать, так как задача обучающая, и до этого еще не дошли.

Comment: Да. Соответствует условию задания: "...выводит на экран в одну строку значения, которые встречаются в нём более одного раза". "2" и "8" встречаются 1 раз.

Comment: Сорян, поторопился с выводами:)

Comment: *Объясните, пожалуйста, что не так?* Вы не обрабатываете последнюю пару - ибо условие `if s[i] == s[i + 1] and s[i + 1] != s[i + 2]:` проверяет ТРОЙКИ.

Comment: Почему тогда не работает с вводом "1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2"?

Comment: @EgoBox Вам надо проверять условие **либо третье число отличается, либо третье число за окончанием строки** (сначала, конечно, нужно проверять выход за строку, чтобы ошибка индексации не получилась, а потом уже 3-е число) и цикл должен быть на один элемент больше соответственно. А ещё у вас фактически переменная `cnt` лишняя и может быть сокращена. У неё всегда значение 2 там, где её `if` проверяет.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Простой вариант исправления - добавляем также проверку на достижение конца строки (оценивается раньше использования индекса!)

```
for i in range(l-1):
    if i == l-2 or s[i + 1] != s[i + 2]:
        if s[i] == s[i + 1]:
            print(s[i], end=" ")
```

Comment: это работает?.. попробовал для s = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2,] l = len(s) - совсем ничего не выводит

Comment: @Jack_oS для указанного примера [выдаёт](https://ideone.com/BgXaQx) 1 2

Comment: ок, может я что-то не то делал...

Answer (score 1):

можно и без set, и без count (до которых вы еще не дошли), и без... сортировки, а используя словарь для подсчета количества повторов каждого числа в списке:

```
numbers = [int(i) for i in input().split()]
nums_counter = dict()

for n in numbers:
    nums_counter[n] = nums_counter.get(n, 0) + 1
```

при исходном "4 8 0 3 4 2 0 3", в `nums_counter` будет следующее:

```
{0: 2, 2: 1, 3: 2, 4: 2, 8: 1}
```

и вывести на печать те, что есть в исходном больше 1-го раза:

```
for k, v in nums_counter.items():
    if v > 1:
        print(k, end=' ')
```

в итоге:

```
0 3 4
```

ps
для `1 1 2 2 3 3` вывод - `1 2 3`
для `1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2` вывод - `1 2`

Answer (score -1):

способ 1:

```
arr = list(map(int, input().split()))

res = [i for i in set(arr) if arr.count(i) > 1]

print(*res)
```

способ 1.5:

```
arr = list(map(int, input().split()))

res = set(filter(lambda i: arr.count(i) > 1, arr))

print(*res)
```

cпособ 2:

```
arr = sorted(list(map(int, input().split())))

res = [arr[i] for i in range(len(arr) - 1) if arr[i] == arr[i+1] and (i == 0 or arr[i] != arr[i-1])]

print(*res)
```

способ 3:

```
arr = list(map(int, input().split()))

res = [arr[i] for i in range(len(arr)) if arr[i] not in arr[:i] and arr[i] in arr[i+1:]]

print(*res)
```

тут результат не отсортирован, но если требуется - можно или `arr` или `res` отсортировать

Answer (score -1):

Я написал так:

```
s = [int(i) for i in input().split()]
s.sort()
a = []

ss = 0
c = 0
for i in s:
    if ss == 0:
        k = i
        ss = 1

        if c == 0:
            c += 1
            continue

        if k == kk:
            a.append(i)
    else:
        kk = i
        ss = 0

        if kk == k:
            a.append(i)

for i in a:
    print(i)
```

Для заданных значений работает, но можно и короче, если подумать